# Trigger multiple links to download files

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a webpage where I can find a random number of files to download. I wanted to develop a little FireFox extension to download all files at once. So far I have the following function to download these files:

```
function getFilesJQ () {
    var $dlLinks = $('a').filter(function(index) { return $(this).text() === "Download"; });

    $dlLinks.each(function () {
        $(this).trigger('click');
    });
}
```

The problem is, that only the first link is clicked and the corresponding file starts to download. The others are not triggered.

Where lies the problem? Is this even possible?

**Edit:**

This is how $dlLinks looks like:

```
{…}
0: <a id="exerciseResourcesForm:a3:0:linkDownload" href="#" onclick="if(typeof jsfcljs == 'function'){jsfcljs(document.getElementById('exerciseResourcesForm'),{'exerciseResourcesForm:a3:0:linkDownload':'exerciseResourcesForm:a3:0:linkDownload'},'');}return false">
1: <a id="exerciseResourcesForm:a3:1:linkDownload" href="#" onclick="if(typeof jsfcljs == 'function'){jsfcljs(document.getElementById('exerciseResourcesForm'),{'exerciseResourcesForm:a3:1:linkDownload':'exerciseResourcesForm:a3:1:linkDownload'},'');}return false">
2: <a id="exerciseResourcesForm:a3:2:linkDownload" href="#" onclick="if(typeof jsfcljs == 'function'){jsfcljs(document.getElementById('exerciseResourcesForm'),{'exerciseResourcesForm:a3:2:linkDownload':'exerciseResourcesForm:a3:2:linkDownload'},'');}return false">
3: <a id="exerciseResourcesForm:a3:3:linkDownload" href="#" onclick="if(typeof jsfcljs == 'function'){jsfcljs(document.getElementById('exerciseResourcesForm'),{'exerciseResourcesForm:a3:3:linkDownload':'exerciseResourcesForm:a3:3:linkDownload'},'');}return false">
length: 4
prevObject: Object { 0: a, 1: a, 2: a, … }
__proto__: Object { jquery: "3.2.1 -ajax,-ajax/jsonp,-ajax/load,-ajax/parseXML,-ajax/script,-ajax/var/location,-ajax/var/nonce,-ajax/var/rquery,-ajax/xhr,-manipulation/_evalUrl,-event/ajax,-effects,-effects/Tween,-effects/animatedSelector", constructor: r(), length: 0, … }
jack_download.js:10:2
```

When one of those links is clicked, to POST requests are issued:

```
POST 
https://*******/emp/ExerciseEdit.jsf 
[HTTP/1.1 200 OK 28ms]
POST 
https://sb-ssl.google.com/safebrowsing/clientreport/download 
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 109ms]
```

Comment: please show how `$dlLinks` looks like

Comment: @brk Done. .....

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).trigger('click');
```

This probably opens the link on the current page, which terminates the current page. You may try to open it in a new one:

```
window.open(this.href, "Download");
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing to take into consideration it the `target` attribute of these links. If the `target` is not defined, then your `click` action is going to open a new session, and your subsequent downloads will be cancelled. One simple way around this is to "force" these links to open in new windows:

```
function getFilesJQ () {
    var $dlLinks = $('a').filter(function(index) { return $(this).text() === "Download"; });

    $dlLinks.each(function () {
        window.open(this.href);
    });
}
```

However, please be aware that your browser may interpret this as multiple popups and try to block them. You may also have to turn off your popup blocker.

Comment: I see your point. Makes sense. I guess the issue now is that the links have onclick events. Several tabs do open now, but not a single file is downloaded (check the `$dlLinks` object in my question edit).

Comment: Do you see any content in the tabs that are opened?

Comment: Yes, it is basically the "Overview" page of the webpage (https://******/emp/Overview.jsf#)

Comment: What's probably happening is that those links are not really "links". They probably trigger a function on the `onclick` event and use some other logic to initiate a download. So the `href` is probably not the real link. But, if that's the case, then your initial attempt (triggering the click) should work. Have you tried debugging?

Comment: That's what bothering me. As I said, the first link is clicked, the subsequent ones are not. The browser console does not show any error.

Comment: Not sure if it helps: two POST requests are issued when one of those links is clicked (see my edit).